# (Fluent) NHibernate: Map complete table to one object

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following database table:

```
Settings

Key            | Value
---------------|-------------------
SomeSetting    | Foo
AnotherSetting | Bar
...            | ...
```

And want to map this to the following object:

```
public class Settings
{
      public virtual string SomeSetting { get; set; }

      public virtual string AnotherSetting { get; set; }
}
```

How could I accomplish this using (Fluent) NHibernate?

Comment: can yo uhave multiple entries of Setting in your table from the  model it doesnt seem so

Comment: check this out: http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/8263d39d4147fa83?fwc=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would map the key/value pairs to a private IDictionary and expose the properties by accessing the dictionary. See [Ayende's blog entry on map](http://ayende.com/blog/4045/nhibernate-mapping-map) for creating the dictionary. Something like:

```
public class Settings
{
    private IDictionary<string, string> _dict;

    //initialize dictionary in constructor
    public Settings()
    {
         _dict = new Dictionary<string, string> { {"SomeSetting", string.Empty} };
    }

    public virtual string SomeSetting
    {
        get { return _dict["SomeSetting"]; }
        set { _dict["SomeSetting"] = value; }
    }

    // etc.

}
```

Comment: This comes closest to what I want. Unfortunate that the `Settings` object has to be changed to accomplish this but there seems to be no way to do this using NHibernate only.

Answer (score 0):

Well an alternate would be to have two columns: Key,Value

map them into a column in the database and now  write a repository class with properties will be responsible for querying the database on the key and getting the value. your repository model might resemble your current object model.

```
public class Settings
{
      private readonly ISession _session;
      public Settings(ISEssion session)
      {
      _session=session;
      }
      public Setting SomeSetting { get {return session.QueryOver<Setting>().SingleOrDefault(x.Key=="SomeSetting "} }

}
```

what do you think?

Comment: We currently have something like that in place but I was wondering if it could be done without changing the database or `Settings` object.